# Apply list of funtions to list of iterables

Tags: python

I need to code a function that accepts two lists as inputs (a list of iterables, a list of some subset of the functions 'len', 'sum', and 'type')

The function should return a list of the same length as the first list, where every element in that list is a *tuple* which has had the functions from the second list applied on them.

---

This is my current code, but it only returns the right answer to the first items of obj and funcs:

```
def apply (list_items, list_funcs):
    list1 = ()
    for n in list_items:
        tup = ()
        for f in list_funcs:
            tup += (f(n),)
        return tup
        list1 += tup

    return list1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply loop over each item and apply the functions to that item

```
def apply(items, funcs):

    output = []
    #Loop over the items
    for item in items:
        #Apply function over each item and add it to result
        output.append(tuple(func(item) for func in funcs))

    return output

print(apply([(1,2),[3,4]], [len, sum, type]))
print(apply([(1,2),[1,3,4,5,6,7],[0]], [len,sum]))
```

The output will be

```
[(2, 3, <class 'tuple'>), (2, 7, <class 'list'>)]
[(2, 3), (6, 26), (1, 0)]
```

Or a one-liner list comprehension

```
def apply(items, funcs):

    # Loop over the items, apply function over each item and add it to result
    output = [ tuple(func(item) for func in funcs) for item in items ]

    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
objs = [(1,2),[1,3,4,5,6,7],[0]]
funcs = [len,sum]
m = [list(map(fun, objs)) for fun in funcs]
list(zip(m[0],m[1]))
```

Output:

```
[(2, 3), (6, 26), (1, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
x=[(1,2),[3,4]]
f=[len,sum,type]
z=[map(y,x) for y in f]
result=[tuple(z[j][i] for j in range(len(z))) for i in range(len(z[0]))]
```